# Instead of PHP In, How can I do And?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking at an application where we can tag items. Currently, if we search for more than 1 tag, then results with content for with either tag appears. it is inclusive rather than exclusive. This is the code which causes it:

```
//app/content/Search/Mysql/Query.php:232
$tagWhere = array( $itemsOnlyTagSearch . \GDP\Db::i()->in( 'index_item_index_id', $tagIds ) );
```

For example, if I search for the tags "windows" and "ios" then content with windows OR iOS tagged come back.

I want to update that line of code so only content with BOTH "windows" and "ios" tagged come back. How can I do that?

Comment: well there is no "get from db that matches all elements from array", you will need to restructure your query to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What library are you using to construct your queries?

Right now, your query is something like

`SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE index_item_index_id in (id1, id2)`
where `id1` and `id2` refers to the tagIds.
You need to modify your query to use multiple `where column = value` expressions, e.g.

`SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE index_item_index_id = id1 AND index_item_index_id = id2)`

It depends on your ORM / Query Class how to construct such SQL query in PHP.